# plumberDeploy::do_provision() - Error: Size is not available in this region

Tags: r, deployment, digital-ocean, plumber

I am trying to provision droplet on DigitalOcean with `plumberDeploy` R package.

I am running:

```
mydrop <- plumberDeploy::do_provision()
```

And getting back:

```
THIS ACTION COSTS YOU MONEY!
Provisioning a new server for which you will get a bill from DigitalOcean.
Using default ssh keys: work_R_laptop
Error: Size is not available in this region.
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may not be a solution for the size issue, but you can specify the droplet-id or hostname as a paramter, so I can suggest that you manually create the droplet from DigitalOcean access panel and the run:

`id <- plumberDeploy::do_provision("your droplet hostname", example=FALSE)`.

Then it should run the setup for the given droplet as expected.